# What methods can I use to get a rank?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am building a ranking system. To get a rank of an item, I have considered using ratio and method.

Let's say I have an item with 10 wins and 10 losses.

Ratio: 10/20 = 0.5
Point: 10 - 10 = 0

What other options do I have?

Comment: A related question on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6019/calculating-the-most-helpful-review

Comment: @Jonas Meyer // thank you for the link. I am not looking for an answer. I like to know other methods as well. I already know ratio and point method. I am sure that there are much more ways to decide a rank of something.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say you are not looking for an answer.  I doubt that the MathOverflow question is the same as yours, but you will notice that the ranking methods mentioned there are not only what you call ratio and point methods.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer // my mistake. I will read the article again!

Comment: Have you looked at Wikipedia entry on [Ranking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Strategies_for_assigning_rankings)?

Answer (score 1):

The ranking problem comes up in many contexts. People who want to rank American college football teams have come up with the BCS system. Part of this involves asking experts for their opinions, but part of it is purely mathematical. Start with the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowl_Championship_Series).

Chess players also get ranked, by the Elo system. Here's a [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system).

Comment: +1 for Elo (Its a great rating system) although it debatable whether it is applicable to the situation at hand. It is mainly used as an indicator for playing strength and thus may not be suitable to rank comments (in some version it takes into account how long ago you played).